# How to test for an empty table using KIF?

Tags: ios, uitableview, kif

I'm using the [KIF test framework](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF). Currently, I'm able to detect that a table is **not** empty by the following line:

```
tester().waitForCellAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), 
    inTableViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier: "My Table")
```

However, I need to be able to test if a table is completely empty. What is the best way to accomplish this using KIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You can grab the table and then perform any action you want against it:

```
//Helper function
extension KIFUITestActor {
    func waitForViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier(accessibilityIdentifier: String) -> UIView? {
        var view: UIView?
        self.waitForAccessibilityElement(nil, view: &view, withIdentifier: accessibilityIdentifier, tappable: false)
        return view
    }
}

if let myTable = tester().waitForViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier("My Table") as? UITableView {
    XCTAssertNil(myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)), "My Table should have been empty.")
}
```

Since table views can have N number of sections that serve different purposes, it doesn't make much sense for KIF to try to provide a test helper to check for an "empty table".

**Edit: I added the helper function definition that was missing from this answer**